# input value doesnt be updated with jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to change, the value of an input in jquery but it dosent work.
Here is my code,

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js">
$('#two').click(function(){
$('#count').val('2');
});

$('#four').click(function(){
$('#count').val('4');
});
</script>

<input type="button" id ='two' value="2Q">
<input  type="button" id ='four' value="4Qy">

Total <input type="text" id="count" value="">
```

Comment: wrap code by [document ready handler](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: thanks, it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for your document to be ready before attaching listeners to the input fields.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#two').on('click', function() {
    $('#count').val('2');
  });
});
</script>

<input type="button" id ='two' value="2Q">
<input  type="button" id ='four' value="4Qy">

Total <input type="text" id="count" value="">
```

Answer (score 2):

Two issues:

1. You can't have both a `src` **and** content in a single `script` element. You need to use two `script` elements.
2. Your code is running *before* the elements it acts on are present in the DOM. Move the `script` with your code to the *bottom* of the page, just before the closing `</body>` tag. (Or use jQuery's [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready), if you don't control where the `script` tags go in the page, as is the case with some CMS systems.)

E.g.

```
<body>
<!-- .... -->
<input type="button" id='two' value="2Q">
<input type="button" id='four' value="4Qy">Total
<input type="text" id="count" value="">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
  $('#two').click(function() {
    $('#count').val('2');
  });

  $('#four').click(function() {
    $('#count').val('4');
  });
</script>
</body>
```

Example:

```html
<input type="button" id='two' value="2Q">
<input type="button" id='four' value="4Qy">Total
<input type="text" id="count" value="">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
  $('#two').click(function() {
    $('#count').val('2');
  });

  $('#four').click(function() {
    $('#count').val('4');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @PranavCBalan: `ready` is for when you don't control where the `script` tags go.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : Yes, if he moved code to the end then it will works

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm demo

```js
$('#two').click(function(){
$('#count').val('2');
});

$('#four').click(function(){
$('#count').val('4');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id ='two' value="2Q">
<input  type="button" id ='four' value="4Qy">

Total <input type="text" id="count" value="">
```